# Automatic redirect when selecting 3rd dropdown in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have 3 typeahead fields:

They are as follows:

Country: |***_*__*_*__*_*____**|

State:   |***_*__*_*__*_*____**|

City:    |***_*__*_*__*_*____**|

Here is the code for the second typeahead field (the rest are similar):

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;"
data-provide="typeahead"  data-items="4"
data-source="["Alabama","Alaska",
               <many more US states>
              ,"Wyoming"]">
```

Now ... I need both typeahead fields to look like dropdowns which can be achieved by following instructions here.. no problem.

- https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21368/bootstrap-combobox/index.html

The question I'm asking pertains to the "Last Option" below:
Note: I am building this in Rails, so ruby code would be nice...

**Placeholder Case:**

I need each of the drop down lists to have a default placeholder text which is grayed out.

eg:

Country: |**_*USA*__*_*__*_*_**|

State:   |**_*IOWA*__*_*__*_***|

City:    |**_*DES MOINES*____**|

**Missing Value Case:**

If the user types in a City value that does not exist in the autocomplete, I want to show them a dropdown with a link..

eg: User types in "yahoo" in City field. This should result in the output "That city does not exist, click here to search for it"

Clicking on the above text should redirect me to Google.com

**Error Case:**

If nothing is selected in the first field (country).. the second field should have a default value in the dropdown: "Please select a Country to begin"

**Last Option:**

upon successful selection of a City, eg: San Francisco ... I want to make a redirect to a new html file like "mysite.com/datastore/calsan.html" (first three letters from each selection in lowercase appended together)

this final html file will be pre-generated and will have relevant statistics and fun facts about the city "San Francisco"... I'll also have fun facts for other cities pregenerated in the datastore folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Last Option**

There seems to be a simple way to do this with inline javascript and option value. I think I will be using this simpler way..

http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/f/blfaqddredirect.htm

**Placeholder Case and All other Cases**

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

The above library solves all my issues and is very powerful! Its not for bootstrap but I don't mind until bootstrap has a comparable option.

Answer (score 8):

See my snippets below

**Placeholder case**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combobox').combobox({placeholder: "Type Something.."});
  });
</script>
```

**Last Option**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.combobox').change(function(){
      if($(this).val().length > 0){
        var fileName = $(this).val().substr(0,3); // this is for getting the first 3 characters, apply the same logic wherever necessary
        window.location("/datastrore/" + fileName + ".html");
      }   
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help in the above two cases.. esp. the "Last Option" case.. could you/someone else also help out with the two other cases?

Comment: For the missing value case, you need to tweak the combobox js code. The error case can again be done using a similar javascript which I have mentioned above

Comment: see here for reference: http://www.slugbooks.com ...Are they using javascript to solve the cases? If so, how?

Comment: Of course, they are doing it using javascript, but they are using a different js plugin, the plugin which you are using does not give that much of a flexibility to do the features mentioned in the link